# Are there numbers that can be split into a geometric sequence in multiple ways?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

The number $91216$ is fun, because $9$, $12$, $16$ is a strictly increasing geometric sequence of length at least three. Does there exist a number that is fun in multiple ways?

The problem can be generalized to have bases other than $10$. Then for any base larger than $32$ we can just use the number $(1,2,4,8,16,32)$ and split it in either $(1)$, $(2)$, $(4)$, $(8)$, $(16)$, $(32)$ or $(1,2)$, $(4,8)$, $(16,32)$. I don't know a solution for any other base.

If leading zeroes are allowed, then $100100010000$ always works giving either $100$, $1000$, $10000$ or $1$, $00100$, $010000$. Even if the sequences are supposed to have different lengths, we can use $100001010000100010000100000$ giving either $1000010$, $100001000$, $10000100000$ or $1$, $000010$, $100$, $001000$, $10000$, $100000$. Therefore, I do not allow the use of leading zeroes.

Comment: I assume "strictly increasing geometric sequence" includes "of length at least $3$"? Cause otherwise $91216$ works, since $9,1216$ would be a strictly increasing geometric sequence.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: How high did you code/check up to?

Comment: In base $10$ I verified there are no solutions of at most $15$ digits.

Comment: What a weird question lol. Can you prove that, for base $10$, concatenating the first $N$ powers of $2$ never works?

Comment: I really have no clue as to how to tackle this problem. I'm generally not very experienced with digit-based problems in general. I was making a programming exercise to determine for a bunch of $15$-digit numbers whether they are fun or not. So I listed all fun $15$-digit numbers and thereby noticed that all numbers appeared only once, so that lead me to this question.